# Audio and video metadata info in Nautilus list view

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-extensions

I've used Nautilus Columns for previous Ubuntu releases but this is not working now in Ubuntu 17.10. Does anyone have solution for this?

Comment: Please add more details about how it's not working.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex It can't be installed now because there is no version for Artful Aardvark in  PPA for nautilus-columns. I found this as a workaround but don't know how to make it work : (http://www.overclock.net/t/515783/how-to-adding-metadata-columns-in-nautilus-ubuntu) .